# how can I show multiple objects of a multiple objects using django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
if co is None:
    try:
      address = **Contract**.objects.filter(address= servicesearch)
      print(address)
    except Contract.DoesNotExist:
      address= None

    for add in address:
      co = add.contractservices_set.all()
      print(co)
```

the first query yields <QuerySet [<Contract: Contract object (52)>, <Contract: Contract object (55)>]>

the second query yields <QuerySet [<Contractservices: Contractservices object (88)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (89)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (90)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (91)>]>
<QuerySet [<Contractservices: Contractservices object (98)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (101)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (102)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (99)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (103)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (100)>, <Contractservices: Contractservices object (104)>]>

All Good....

However, when I am trying to render the results its only showing the **contract **objects of 55. I want to show both **contract **objects 52 and 55. please help...

my paginator view is..

```
 paginator = Paginator(co,8)
    if request.GET.get('page') == None:
        page_number = 1
    else:
        page_number =request.GET.get('page')
      
    DataFinal=paginator.get_page(page_number)
    totalpage =DataFinal.paginator.num_pages
```

I cant change the template as it is just one search criteria among many..
`your text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set only `co` in the paginated result.

You have to set only one query for getting Contract with ContractServices attached together:

```py
address = Contract.objects.filter(address=servicesearch)
address = address.prefetch_related("contractservices_set")

...

paginator = Paginator(address, 8)
if request.GET.get('page') == None:
    page_number = 1
else:
    page_number =request.GET.get('page')
      
DataFinal = paginator.get_page(page_number)

...
# in the html
{% for address in DataFinal %}
    {% for service in address.contractservices_set.all %}
        {{service.XXX}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```